# DataTables: alterning the output after the table has been built via json

Tags: jquery, json, datatable

I've recently made the transition from building my tables in HTML and using DataTables to redraw them to populating the data from JSON.

I'm struggling however to figure out how to make replacements to the data that's written to the dom.

example (not a real example lol):
I have a string in columnA which is a description that reads...

> to use a quotation mark hold down shift and press 2, this will make
>   them appear, like so "

if I try and send that sentence in a JSON, the JSON will become invalid. The way I have gotten around this is by replacing ' " ' to ' quotation-mark ' at the point the JSON is created. This works fine and the JSON is valid but it means the sentence now reads...

> to use a quotation mark hold down shift and press 2, this will make
>   them appear, like soquotation-mark

What I need ideally is the relevant syntax to alter what DataTables writes in the dom. The JSON also writes span elements with custom properties that may also include a quotation mark so I can't just alter the cell per-se.

My current code for writing the table is as follows:

```
                    $("#table9").DataTable({
                        "sScrollX": "90%",
                        "sScrollXInner": "100%",
                        "ajax": "Ajax.asp?RT=weeklyData",
                        "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]]
                    });
```

I could do a blanket search over the entire dom after the DataTable has been rendered and then replace the offending phrases but it seems very wasteful and inefficient.

Any input of a better resolve would be much apreciated

Thanks in advance folks

elboffor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datatables offers a few options in this case. Checkout:

https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render
https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.createdCell

If I were you I'd probably use the createdCell option to manipulate the td element before its appended to the DOM.

```
$("#table9").DataTable({
    "sScrollX": "90%",
    "sScrollXInner": "100%",
    "ajax": "Ajax.asp?RT=weeklyData",
    "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
    "columnDefs": [ {
        "targets": 0,
        "createdCell": function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col){
            $(td).html($(td).html().replace(/quotation-mark/g,"quotation-mark-replacement"));
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply William,
 Just going to check it out now and see how I get on :) I'll accept as answer once I can confirm. (I do wish the datatables team hired a site writer to convert the documentation to English instead of pure dev speak)

Comment: I do have one question, would I need to specify all the columns in the table? if so I assume I would need to loop through or add each column individually?

Comment: actualy, looking at the documentation I may be able to simply not declare the columns at all and omit "data" then just use createdCell on its own to parse all the cells https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.createdCell

Comment: the columns property is an array you can add all of your column settings to that array. The option allows you to specify what parts of the json you want to display without the need to fully build the DOM. If you don't want to do that I think you can use columnDefs instead of columns. However with columnsDefs you need to use the column index as the target instead of the json property.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the differences @William :),

I haven't declared the column names in the JSON so using the index is easier for me. Was testing it by changing index2 but it's not firing. 

Any ideas for the .replace() part of the code?

below is what I have so far:

        `"ajax": "Ajax.asp?RT=weeklyData",

        "columnDefs": [ {

            "targets": 2,

            "createdCell": function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col){

                $(td).replace(/quotation-mark/g,"test");

            }

        }],

        "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]]`

Comment: got it working but only for the first instance found. any ideas?
            "createdCell": function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col){
                $(td).html($(td).html().replace(/quotation-mark/g,"test"));
            }
edit, must have had some cache data working against me, after a couple of refreshes all is good (and I should think so seeing as I ticked global) updated your answer and marked it correct :)

Comment: Try using the render method instead of the createdCell method. "render": function(data, type, row) { return data.replace(/quotation-mark/g,"test"); }

Comment: oo
now that sounds a hell of a lot more sensible